# evidence that somebody is who they say that they are

Tags: vocabulary, free-relative-clauses

> evidence that somebody is **who they say that they are** ([OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bona-fides))

It seems like the bold structure is a fused relative; ‘*that they are*’ is the content clause of ‘*say*’; there is a gap after ‘*you are*.’ Then what are co-indexed? I would think ‘*who*’ being able to be interpreted ‘*the person who*,’ ‘*who*’ in which is co-indexed with the gap after ‘*they are.*’ How do I have to understand the structure?

> evidence that somebody is [ the person who *(i)* [ they say [that they are __ *(i)* ] ] ].

Comment: Perhaps also consider subordinate interrogative clauses (compare to [21.i] on page 977 in 2002 *CGEL*). Remember that, in today's standard English, "who" as a fused relative word is usually used as an alternate for the "whoever" form in the *free choice* constructions (page 1076 bottom); and that otherwise, when "who" is used as a fused relative, it is usually only found in archaisms (e.g. "Who steals my purse steals trash" -- Shakespeare's *Othello*).

Comment: The idiom does not use "that", BTW. `Are you really who you say you are? Is he who he says he is?`

Comment: @F.E. Thanks to you I've read on 'interrogative content clause.' So 'who' is a fronted interrogative; the bold part in the example above is a specifying PC. And we could say that the interrogate and the gap has unbounded dependency.

Comment: @TimRomano Note that the OP copied that excerpt from *Oxford Learner's Dictionaries*. And since the expression means what the individual words themselves mean, the expression probably wouldn't be considered an idiom.

Comment: @F.E. I do not understand your comment: "The expression means what the individual words themselves mean". What I'm saying is that native speakers of American English would not say  "...who they say that they are" but "...who they say  they are", and I've never heard a native British speaker in everyday speech say it that way either. It strikes me as "hypercorrect". Write a sentence asking me if I'm who I say I am: `Are you who you say you are?` is idiomatic, `Are you who you say that you are?` is not.

Comment: @TimRomano The OP **copied** the excerpt from an online dictionary. So it seems that that dictionary doesn't see anything wrong with that expression (though, some dictionaries are better or worse than others). Also, here's a definition of ***idiom*** from a dictionary: *a group of words established by usage as having a meaning not deducible from those of the individual words (e.g., rain cats and dogs, see the light)* -- which is basically what I said in my previous comment.

Comment: That's not the only meaning, @F.E. `Idiomatic: using, containing, or denoting expressions that are natural to a native speaker.`

Comment: @TimRomano But that's the definition of ***idiomatic***, not of ***idiom***. :) . . . (Wait, are you using the same dictionary that I am? iMac's *New Oxford American Dictionary*?)

Comment: @F.E. Check out definition #1 of `idiom` in the OED. `The form of speech peculiar or proper to a people or country...` So we could say, in the idiom of American English, "that" would not appear in this locution; and probably not in British English either.

Comment: Just to be clear: I'm talking about what you would hear on the street. `Are you who you say you are? Is she who she says she is? Are they who they say they are?` are the natural forms of this locution. Inserting "that" is hypercorrect, evidence of adherence to some prescriptive grammatical rule, rather than an example of natural use of the tongue.

Comment: @TimRomano Please start up your own question thread. (Aside: Your claims don't hold much water, because the OP **COPIED** that excerpt from an online dictionary.)

Comment: I don't think it's a hypercorrection.  It sounds fine to me, anyway, though it's significantly more common without *that*.  As for *idiom*, usage distinguishes these meanings: "X is an idiom" means that X is non-compositional, which this is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you phrase a statement as *"Bob says he's a licensed masseuse"* as opposed to simply saying *"Bob is a licensed masseuse"*, you are implicitly calling the fact into question... or at least distancing yourself from repeating his claim as fact.  You are reporting what Bob said; and because you feel the need to point out that you are merely a reporter, it carries a tone of doubt.  You do not feel comfortable stating anything as fact of what he "is" or what he "is not"...only repeating *what he said*.

Following that, this "being who you say you are" may be more clear if phrased as:

> I need proof that you are who you claim to be.

But that is in usage equivalent to:

> I need proof that you are who you say you are.